# Check if video is playable on browsers by Javascript

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video

I have a video tag in my video-sharing website

```
<video src="/video-123"></video>
```

The video is uploaded by users, which can be MP4, MOV,... and can be played on some browser, while others cannot (based on video encoding, for example H.264 is widely supported, but H.265 or HEVC only supported on newer Safari).
In the case the browser cannot play the video, I want to detect by Javascript on that browser, in order to show an error message to users. How can I do that? Please help me.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource/isTypeSupported perhaps

Answer (score 1):

Just insert any HTML tag inside `<video>` tag. Browsers which are supporting video format just will replace it.

```
<video src="/video-123">
  <div>Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</div>
</video>
```

or:

```
<video>
  <source src="/video-123.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="/video-123.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  
  <div>Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</div>
  
</video>
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he needed. He is not asking if browser supports html5 video or not but if video can actually play or display

Answer (score 0):

u can use html5 video player test
[working js-demo](https://js-demo.com/index.php?ref=d4594ff9526f)

```
// https://gist.github.com/joe-watkins/710e5aa49a35382d6464

var html5VideoTest = function(){
    
    var player = document.getElementById("video-player"),
            loader = document.getElementById("video-loading"),
            autoplay = false; // The <video> element


            function detect_autoplay(acceptable_delay){

                    // create video element
                    var autoplay_test_content = document.createElement('video');

                    //create mp4 and webm sources, 5s long
                    var mp4 = document.createElement('source');
                    mp4.src = "data:video/mp4;base64,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";

                    var webm = document.createElement('source');
                    webm.src = "data:video/webm;base64,GkXfo49CgoR3ZWJtQoeBAUKFgQEYU4BnAQAAAAAAF60RTZt0vE27jFOrhBVJqWZTrIIQA027jFOrhBZUrmtTrIIQbE27jFOrhBFNm3RTrIIXmU27jFOrhBxTu2tTrIIWs+xPvwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFUmpZuQq17GDD0JATYCjbGliZWJtbCB2MC43LjcgKyBsaWJtYXRyb3NrYSB2MC44LjFXQY9BVlNNYXRyb3NrYUZpbGVEiYRFnEAARGGIBc2Lz1QNtgBzpJCy3XZ0KNuKNZS4+fDpFxzUFlSua9iu1teBAXPFhL4G+bmDgQG5gQGIgQFVqoEAnIEAbeeBASMxT4Q/gAAAVe6BAIaFVl9WUDiqgQEj44OEE95DVSK1nIN1bmTgkbCBULqBPJqBAFSwgVBUuoE87EQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB9DtnVB4eeBAKC4obaBAAAAkAMAnQEqUAA8AABHCIWFiIWEiAICAAamYnoOC6cfJa8f5Zvda4D+/7YOf//nNefQYACgnKGWgQFNANEBAAEQEAAYABhYL/QACIhgAPuC/rOgnKGWgQKbANEBAAEQEAAYABhYL/QACIhgAPuC/rKgnKGWgQPoANEBAAEQEAAYABhYL/QACIhgAPuC/rOgnKGWgQU1ANEBAAEQEAAYABhYL/QACIhgAPuC/rOgnKGWgQaDANEBAAEQEAAYABhYL/QACIhgAPuC/rKgnKGWgQfQANEBAAEQEAAYABhYL/QACIhgAPuC/rOgnKGWgQkdANEBAAEQEBRgAGFgv9AAIiGAAPuC/rOgnKGWgQprANEBAAEQEAAYABhYL/QACIhgAPuC/rKgnKGWgQu4ANEBAAEQEAAYABhYL/QACIhgAPuC/rOgnKGWgQ0FANEBAAEQEAAYABhYL/QACIhgAPuC/rOgnKGWgQ5TANEBAAEQEAAYABhYL/QACIhgAPuC/rKgnKGWgQ+gANEBAAEQEAAYABhYL/QACIhgAPuC/rOgnKGWgRDtANEBAAEQEAAYABhYL/QACIhgAPuC/rOgnKGWgRI7ANEBAAEQEAAYABhYL/QACIhgAPuC/rIcU7trQOC7jLOBALeH94EB8YIUzLuNs4IBTbeH94EB8YIUzLuNs4ICm7eH94EB8YIUzLuNs4ID6LeH94EB8YIUzLuNs4IFNbeH94EB8YIUzLuNs4IGg7eH94EB8YIUzLuNs4IH0LeH94EB8YIUzLuNs4IJHbeH94EB8YIUzLuNs4IKa7eH94EB8YIUzLuNs4ILuLeH94EB8YIUzLuNs4INBbeH94EB8YIUzLuNs4IOU7eH94EB8YIUzLuNs4IPoLeH94EB8YIUzLuNs4IQ7beH94EB8YIUzLuNs4ISO7eH94EB8YIUzBFNm3SPTbuMU6uEH0O2dVOsghTM";

                //append sources to test video
                autoplay_test_content.appendChild(webm);
                autoplay_test_content.appendChild(mp4);

                //set attributes -needs to be visible or IE squawks, so we move it way outside
                autoplay_test_content.id = "base64_test_video";
                autoplay_test_content.autoplay = true;
                autoplay_test_content.style.position = "fixed";
                autoplay_test_content.style.left = "5000px";

                //add to DOM
                document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(autoplay_test_content);

                var base64_test_video = document.getElementById("base64_test_video");

                //test for autoplay, 100 ms buffer
                setTimeout(function(){
                        if(!base64_test_video.paused){
                                autoplay = true;
                                document.getElementById("output-support").innerHTML = "True"; // demo
                        }else{
                            document.getElementById("output-support").innerHTML = "False"; // demo
                        }

                        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].removeChild(autoplay_test_content);

                },acceptable_delay);

            }

            var checkBuffered = function(){
                setInterval(function(){
                    if(player.readyState == 4){ // VIDEO IS BUFFERED
                        loader.style.display = "none"; // demo
                        document.getElementById("output-buffered").innerHTML = "True"; // demo
                        player.style.display = "block"; // demo
                        clearInterval(checkBuffered);
                    }
                },400);
            },
            
            init = function(){
                detect_autoplay(100);
                checkBuffered();
            }       
            
            init();

}


html5VideoTest();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the on error event to determine it

//Jquery

```
 $(video).on("error",function(){
  alert("error occured");
});
```

Sometimes due to encoding, some video can play the sound in the video  but won't display pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be very interested to know if anyone has a genuine solution for this.

My experience is H.265/HEVC videos silently fail to render, but give no indication detectable by javsacript.

The `<video>` element does not fire an `error` event when you `play()`. It fires `canplay`, `playing` and `timeupdate` events, just like it does when the video is working. But nothing is rendered to the screen.